# Swift Tuples as Dictionary Values in Swift 5

Tags: ios, swift, swift5

I have a Dictionary with a key of type String and values as a tuple:

```
var dictionaryTuple = [String: (x: Double, y: Double)]()
```

How do I set and access the values of the tuple. This is what I tried

`dictionaryTuple["One"].x = 5.5` - compiler gives an error: Value of optional type '(x: Double, y: Double)?' must be unwrapped to refer to member 'x' of wrapped base type '(x: Double, y: Double)' see playground screenshot below
Not sure why the compiler is giving an error. I have not declared the tuple as optional or the dictionary as an optional
[image]

When I change to:
`dictionaryTuple["One"]?.x = 5.5` - compiler is happy but I am not getting any value back
[image]

If I change it to:
`dictionaryTuple["One"]!.x = 5.5` - it crashes.
[image]

What am I doing wrong? Do I need to initialize the tuple before using it? if so how?

Thanks very much!

Comment: I think you should use a `CGPoint` instead of a tuple or create a `Point` structure with x and y properties.

Comment: "What am I doing wrong?". You are using optional chaining. This means ignore the right side of the code in case there is no value for that key.

Comment: "Do I need to initialize the tuple before using it?"  Yes. "if so how?" You need to use Dictionary Key-based subscript with default value and provide an initial value to your tuple in case it doesn't exist.

Comment: thanks for your comments. Agreed, I would use CGPoint if I was going to use for an x,y point. I just created this for posting the question. I am using this for creating a tuple of two UIColors!

Comment: You probably don't need a dictionary with a tuple as values either. If you post a question with your actual goal we probably could show you a better solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can insert either a tuple like this

```
dictionaryTuple["One"] = (3.3, 4.4)
```

or update an existing one but then you need to treat it as an optional.

```
dictionaryTuple["Two"]?.x = 5.5
```

or supply a default value when updating.

```
dictionaryTuple["Three", default: (0.0, 0.0)].x = 5.5
```

Performing these 3 operations will mean the dictionary contains 2 tuples

```
var dictionaryTuple = [String: (x: Double, y: Double)]()
dictionaryTuple["One"] = (3.3, 4.4)
dictionaryTuple["Two"]?.x = 5.5
dictionaryTuple["Three", default: (0.0, 0.0)].x = 5.5
print(dictionaryTuple)
```

> ["Three": (x: 5.5, y: 0.0), "One": (x: 3.3, y: 4.4)]

Answer (score 1):

Why not construct your struct like this?

```
struct DT {
    let key: String
    let x: Double
    let y: Double
}

let dt = DT(key: "One", x: 1, y: 2)
```

---

If you really want your own way, same as in your question:

```
struct DT {
    var dictionaryTuple = [String: (x: Double, y: Double)]()
}


var dt = DT(dictionaryTuple: ["One": (x: 1, y: 2)])

print(dt)//prints -> DT(dictionaryTuple: ["One": (x: 1.0, y: 2.0)])

var tuple: (x: Double, y: Double) = dt.dictionaryTuple["One"]!
tuple.x = 100
tuple.y = 200

//apply
dt.dictionaryTuple["One"] = tuple

print(dt)//prints -> DT(dictionaryTuple: ["One": (x: 100.0, y: 200.0)])
```

the key here is that I explicitly declary the type of the `tuple` variable, and cast it.